# How do you create a gradle module that is available to the buildscript classpath of another module?

Tags: gradle

What I need is for my project to have a subproject that produces a jar which is available to the buildscript classpath of another subproject. From what I've read, I need to use a composite build to achieve this. I'm trying to structure the project like so:

```
root
   test
   test2
```

in the root I have

settings.gradle.kts

```
include("test")
includeBuild("test2")
```

in the test project I have:

test/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
}

group = "github.fatalcatharsis"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

in the settings of the composite build I have

test2/settings.gradle.kts

```
includeBuild("..") {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute(module("github.fatalcatharsis:test")).using(project(":test"))
    }
}
```

Now if I use it as a compile dependency, the substitution works correctly, like so:

test2/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
}

group = "github.fatalcatharsis"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

dependencies {
    implementation("github.fatalcatharsis:test:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

However, If I use it as a buildscript dependency, it fails to resolve saying that the external dependency cannot be found in any repository.

test2/build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("github.fatalcatharsis:test:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
}

group = "github.fatalcatharsis"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

What can I do to have a module that is available to the buildscript classpath of another module?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dependency of a subprojects just like other dependencies, with special project notation. If you wanted to bring test2 into test, you would declare the following in the `build.gradle` of the `test` project.

```
dependencies {
   implementation project(':test2')
}
```

The `:` signifies that gradle should look for a project vs a maven artifact. See the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) for more info!

You wouldn't want to declare it as a buildscript dependency because you are using the dependency to compile your code, not as a dependency to gradle to build your project.